# Integrating CSS star rating into an HTML form

Tags: html, css, forms, rating-system

I've seen a tutorial online - http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/402/CSS-Star-Rating-System - for making a CSS star rating system.

On the page they have this code:

```
<ul class="rating">
   <li><a href="#" title="1 Star">1</a></li> 
   <li><a href="#" title="2 Stars">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="3 Stars">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="4 Stars">4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="5 Stars">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

From what I can tell, this is just a list. How would I integrate it into my form, so that the information from the star rating can be submitted to a database. My current code for the form is below:

```
 <p>Quality</p>
 <input type="radio" name="ratingquality" value="1"> 
 <input type="radio" name="ratingquality" value="2"> 
 <input type="radio" name="ratingquality" value="3"> 
 <input type="radio" name="ratingquality" value="4"> 
 <input type="radio" name="ratingquality" value="5">
```

Comment: Step 1: Throw it away. A bunch of links to the top of the page is no basis for a form control. Step 2: You want to pick exactly one option from a group of five so find something that builds on radio buttons such as [this example I found via Google](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-star-rating/#fig_star_sprite).

Comment: @Quentin make this an answer so I can give you a proper up-vote

Comment: for css only rating system visit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081194/how-to-create-rating-system-using-only-css/23081284#23081284

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is very easy to use, just copy-paste the code. You can use your own star image in background.

I have created a variable `var userRating`. you can use this variable to get value from stars.

Enjoy!! :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Check Radio-box
    $(".rating input:radio").attr("checked", false);

    $('.rating input').click(function () {
        $(".rating span").removeClass('checked');
        $(this).parent().addClass('checked');
    });

    $('input:radio').change(
      function(){
        var userRating = this.value;
        alert(userRating);
    }); 
});
```

```css
.rating {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
}
.rating span { float:right; position:relative; }
.rating span input {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    opacity:0;
}
.rating span label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    background:#ccc;
    font-size:30px;
    margin-right:2px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
}
.rating span:hover ~ span label,
.rating span:hover label,
.rating span.checked label,
.rating span.checked ~ span label {
    background:#F90;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating">
    <span><input type="radio" name="rating" id="str5" value="5"><label for="str5"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="rating" id="str4" value="4"><label for="str4"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="rating" id="str3" value="3"><label for="str3"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="rating" id="str2" value="2"><label for="str2"></label></span>
    <span><input type="radio" name="rating" id="str1" value="1"><label for="str1"></label></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Added a JSfiddle example with your code. Looks great. http://jsfiddle.net/bhpyk18w/

Comment: Its good. But the rated values are not stored anywhere. Can you please add a little more code and description on how we can save the data of already made votes and show the stars lit?

Comment: I made a little change in order to turn the circles into stars. Thank you for the great code.

Answer (score 16):

Here is how to integrate CSS star rating into an HTML form without using javascript (only html and css):

**CSS:**

```
.txt-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.clear {
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}

.rating {
    width: 90px;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.rating > label {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 1.1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
}

.rating > label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ label,
.rating > input.radio-btn:checked ~ label {
    color: transparent;
}

.rating > label:hover:before,
.rating > label:hover ~ label:before,
.rating > input.radio-btn:checked ~ label:before,
.rating > input.radio-btn:checked ~ label:before {
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: #FFD700;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="txt-center">
    <form>
        <div class="rating">
            <input id="star5" name="star" type="radio" value="5" class="radio-btn hide" />
            <label for="star5">☆</label>
            <input id="star4" name="star" type="radio" value="4" class="radio-btn hide" />
            <label for="star4">☆</label>
            <input id="star3" name="star" type="radio" value="3" class="radio-btn hide" />
            <label for="star3">☆</label>
            <input id="star2" name="star" type="radio" value="2" class="radio-btn hide" />
            <label for="star2">☆</label>
            <input id="star1" name="star" type="radio" value="1" class="radio-btn hide" />
            <label for="star1">☆</label>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Please check the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shadiabuhilal/0kwnb7ph/3/)

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.

Comment: this was the best answer in my opinion because it has the least dependencies. Just html+css

Answer (score 3):

How about this? I needed the exact same thing, I had to create one from scratch. It's PURE CSS, and works in IE9+ Feel-free to improve upon it.

Demo: http://www.d-k-j.com/Articles/Web_Development/Pure_CSS_5_Star_Rating_System_with_Radios/

```
<ul class="form">
    <li class="rating">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="0" checked /><span class="hide"></span>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1" /><span></span>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2" /><span></span>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3" /><span></span>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4" /><span></span>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5" /><span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.form {
    margin:0;
}

.form li {
    list-style:none;
}

.hide {
    display:none;
}

.rating input[type="radio"] {
    position:absolute;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity:0;
    -khtml-opacity:0;
    opacity:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:17px;
}

.rating span {
    width:24px;
    height:16px;
    line-height:16px;
    padding:1px 22px 1px 0; /* 1px FireFox fix */
    background:url(stars.png) no-repeat -22px 0;
}

.rating input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
    background-position:-22px 0;
}

.rating input[type="radio"]:checked + span ~ span {
    background-position:0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much answered my question!

Comment: That's not pure CSS tho as it uses image.

Comment: The link redirects to a construction company.

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
.rate-container > i {
    float: right;
}

.rate-container > i:HOVER,
.rate-container > i:HOVER ~ i {
    color: gold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="rate-container">
    <i class="fa fa-star "></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star "></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star "></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star "></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star "></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say right off the bat that you will not be able to achieve the look they have with radio buttons with strictly CSS.

You could, however, stick to the list style in the example you posted and replace the `anchors` with clickable `spans` that would trigger a javascript event that would in turn save that rating to your database via ajax.

If you went that route you would probably also want to save a cookie to the users machine so that they could not submit over and over again to your database. That would prevent them from submitting more than once at least until they deleted their cookies.

But of course there are many ways to address this problem. This is just one of them. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5esr/).

The HTML:

```
<div class="rating">
<span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}
.rating > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.1em;
}
.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
}
```

Hope this helps.

[Source](http://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/)

Comment: Good approach to display stars but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: How can we use this solution with form submission?

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have tried so far?